# How does one add print to a Drupal site?

Tags: drupal

A web page has content, navigation and other non-content items such as menus and headings.
How does one add a print function to all pages on a Drupal web site so that the user
can print a page easily without all of the clutter?

Comment: Should be on Superuser rather than Serverfault?

Comment: I'm thinking more webmasters than superuser, this is the exact type of question for that exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [module](http://drupal.org/project/print).

Answer (score 1):

Use a print-stylesheet, setting i.e. the navigation, ad and commentsection to display=none.
Embed the stylesheet in your head-section of your page.tpl like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/print.css" media="print" />
```

and you are done.
Now everytime a printer is called, the webbrowser will use this stylesheet instead of the normal one.

Comment: Print stylesheets are the way to go. Having to open another page to get to the "print version" of a web page is annoying, redundant and unnecessary. And, of course, this concept applies to web pages outside of Drupal as well.